# Google Compute Engine Random Shutdown

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Our Compute Engine which runs the backend for a mobile game randomly shutdown today (8/3/18) and the logs are unable to tell me which user or IP address initiated it.

I've been doing some digging and got into the Syslogs, which display the following:

```
Mar  8 10:58:10 redis-prod-vm systemd[1]: Started Synchronise Hardware Clock to System Clock.
Mar  8 10:58:10 redis-prod-vm systemd[1]: Stopping Session 5 of user redis.
Mar  8 10:58:10 redis-prod-vm systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 999...
Mar  8 10:58:10 redis-prod-vm systemd[7558]: Stopping Default.
Mar  8 10:58:10 redis-prod-vm systemd[1]: Stopping Graphical Interface.
Mar  8 10:58:10 redis-prod-vm systemd[1]: Stopped target Graphical Interface.
Mar  8 10:58:10 redis-prod-vm systemd[1]: Stopping Entropy daemon using the HAVEGE algorithm...
Mar  8 10:58:10 redis-prod-vm haveged[369]: haveged: Stopping due to signal 15
Mar  8 10:58:10 redis-prod-vm haveged[369]: haveged starting up
Mar  8 10:58:10 redis-prod-vm systemd[1]: Stopping Multi-User System.
Mar  8 10:58:10 redis-prod-vm systemd[1]: Stopped target Multi-User System.
Mar  8 10:58:10 redis-prod-vm systemd[7558]: Stopped target Default.
Mar  8 10:58:10 redis-prod-vm systemd[7558]: Stopping Basic System.
Mar  8 10:58:10 redis-prod-vm systemd[7558]: Stopped target Basic System.
Mar  8 10:58:10 redis-prod-vm systemd[7558]: Stopping Paths.
Mar  8 10:58:10 redis-prod-vm systemd[7558]: Stopped target Paths.
Mar  8 10:58:10 redis-prod-vm systemd[7558]: Stopping Timers.
Mar  8 10:58:10 redis-prod-vm systemd[7558]: Stopped target Timers.
Mar  8 10:58:10 redis-prod-vm systemd[7558]: Stopping Sockets.
Mar  8 10:58:10 redis-prod-vm systemd[7558]: Stopped target Sockets.
Mar  8 10:58:10 redis-prod-vm systemd[7558]: Starting Shutdown.
Mar  8 10:58:10 redis-prod-vm systemd[7558]: Reached target Shutdown.
Mar  8 10:58:10 redis-prod-vm systemd[1]: Stopping Deferred execution scheduler...
Mar  8 10:58:10 redis-prod-vm systemd[1]: Stopping vsftpd FTP server...
Mar  8 10:58:10 redis-prod-vm systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: bitnami init script...
Mar  8 10:58:10 redis-prod-vm systemd[1]: Stopping Regular background program processing daemon...
Mar  8 10:58:10 redis-prod-vm systemd[7558]: Starting Exit the Session...
Mar  8 10:58:10 redis-prod-vm systemd[1]: Stopping Google Compute Engine user shutdown scripts...
Mar  8 10:58:10 redis-prod-vm systemd[1]: Stopping OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
```

This continued until the VM finished shutting down, here's the log:

```
2018-03-08 10:59:46.073 GMT compute.instances.stop {
    "event_timestamp_us":"XXX",
    "actor":{"user":""},
    "resource":{
        "name":"redis-prod-vm",
        "type":"instance",
        "zone":"us-central1-f","id":"XXX"
    },
    "event_type":"GCE_OPERATION_DONE",
    "trace_id":"XXX",
    "operation":{"type":"operation",…
```

I've replaced some potentially important numbers with XXX to be safe.
Can someone please help shed light onto what happened?

Comment: Did you check whether the instance was [preemptive](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preemptible) or not? Is your instance still down? You can check [serial console output](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console) or [stackdriver logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview) which might help you find the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I post this answer to make recommendation provided by *@Taher* at the comment section more visible:

Please have a look at the documentation [Preemptible VM instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preemptible):

> A preemptible VM is an instance that you can create and run at a much
> lower price than normal instances. However, **Compute Engine might stop
> (preempt) these instances if it requires access to those resources for
> other tasks.** Preemptible instances are excess Compute Engine capacity,
> so their availability varies with usage.
>
> If your apps are fault-tolerant and can withstand possible instance
> preemptions, then preemptible instances can reduce your Compute Engine
> costs significantly. For example, batch processing jobs can run on
> preemptible instances. If some of those instances stop during
> processing, the job slows but does not completely stop. Preemptible
> instances complete your batch processing tasks without placing
> additional workload on your existing instances and without requiring
> you to pay full price for additional normal instances.

Please check if your instance is preemptible o not.

Also, you can follow the documentation [Viewing serial port output](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/viewing-serial-port-output) and check if there any useful logging information.

Furthermore, please consider using [Using the Logs Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs-viewer-interface) to collect more troubleshooting information.